# How to elegantly find if an angle is between a range?

Tags: python, math, angle

For example, if my angle is 20 degrees, I can check if it is within [0, 40] like so:

```
lower = 0
upper = 40
if angle > lower and angle < upper:
        print('done')
```

However this logic will not work if my range crosses the 360 degree boundary (e.g. lower=350 and upper=40). I know I can handle this with additional if/else block but is there any elegant way?

Comment: Do you want to switch the values if `lower` is greater than `upper`? Then it is `if min(lower, upper) <= angle <= max(lower, upper):`. BTW, there is no operator `&&` in Python. If you want a logical _and_  then use `and`.

Comment: Or do you want to add `360` if `lower` is greater than `upper`? Then it is `lower <= angle <= (upper if upper > lower else upper + 360)`

Comment: Or he wants to place the angle on a section of a circle. So, for `lower = 350` and `upper = 40` everything between (clockwise) it in the section of a circle, should pass the test. That is every value between `350` and `360` + everything between `0` and `40` degrees,

Comment: Or do you mean `0 < abs(angle-360 if angle > 180 else angle) < 40`?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Sorry for not being clear. If my lower is 350 and upper is 40 degree, it should pass. Because 350 degree is -10 degrees

Comment: use angle % 360 ?

Answer (score 8):

An easy way to do check if `alpha` is between `lower` and `upper` is to mesure angles modulo 360 from `lower`. This gives us positive values between 0 and 360.

We just have to check if (alpha - lower) modulo 360 is smaller than (upper - lower) modulo 360, as you can see on the illustrations:

alpha in the range:

[image: alpha in the range]

alpha out of the range:

[image]

```
def angle_in_range(alpha, lower, upper):
    return (alpha - lower) % 360 <= (upper - lower) % 360


tests = [(25, 20, 40), (15, 20, 40), (45, 20, 40), (10, 350, 20), (-5, 350, 20), (365, 350, 20), (330, 350, 20)]
for alpha, lower, upper in tests:
    print(f'{alpha} between {lower} and {upper}: {angle_in_range(alpha, lower, upper)}')

# 25 between 20 and 40: True
# 15 between 20 and 40: False
# 45 between 20 and 40: False
# 10 between 350 and 20: True
# -5 between 350 and 20: True
# 365 between 350 and 20: True
# 330 between 350 and 20: False
```

Comment: I've used this to calculate a click in the 'out of bounds' zone on a circular gauge. Adding a calculation for the midpoint `((upper - lower) % 360) / 2` allows me to decide if the click is closer to the lower region or the upper and adjust accordingly. So Cheers for this answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that all angles are modulo 360. Then, if the range appears backwards, reverse the condition.

So for example:

```
def in_range(lower, upper, angle):
    lower %= 360
    upper %= 360
    angle %= 360
    if lower > upper:
        return angle >= lower or angle <= upper
    return angle > lower and angle < upper
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compute cross products between the pairs of vectors, and based on their signs find out their relative orientation.

Consider that you have vectors `A`, `B` and `C`
and you want to check whether `C` stays between `A` and `B`.
In this case if the cross products `A x C`, `C x B` and `A x B` have the same sign,
then it does.

In this solution it does not matter which angle is upper and which is lower.

Reference:
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/22392/what-is-a-good-way-to-determine-if-a-vector-is-between-two-other-vectors-in-2d

```
import math


def is_between(angle, first, second):
    angle = math.radians(angle)
    first = math.radians(first)
    second = math.radians(second)

    return (
        sign(cross_product(first, angle)) ==
        sign(cross_product(angle, second)) ==
        sign(cross_product(first, second))
    )


def cross_product(first, second):
    first_x = math.cos(first)
    first_y = math.sin(first)

    second_x = math.cos(second)
    second_y = math.sin(second)

    return first_x * second_y - first_y * second_x


def sign(x):
    return math.copysign(1, x)
```

Tests:

```
import pytest

from angle import is_between


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    'angle, first, second, expected',
    [
        (20, 0, 40, True),
        (20, 30, 10, True),
        (20, 30, 350, True),
        (-5, 30, 350, True),
        (-5, 30, 350, True),
        (40, 30, 350, False),
        (340, 30, 350, False),
        (-20, 30, -10, False),
        (25, 15, 270, False),
        (25, 15, 90, True),
        (25, 15, 194, True),
        (25, 15, 270, False),
        (90, 0, 179, True),
        (90, 0, 181, False),
        (90, 0, -179, False),
    ],
)
def test_is_between(angle, first, second, expected):
    result = is_between(angle, first, second)
    assert result == expected
```